# How to prevent plant irrigation drainage from dripping into my downstairs neighbor's window?

Tags: water, irrigation

We live in the second floor in this building:

[image]

When we water our plants, the water drips into the window of our neighbor in the first floor, and she does not like it at all. We want to keep watering our plants, and at the same time, keep our neighbor's apartment dry.

One solution we thought of was to buy several pieces of this thing:

[image]

and install them on the house wall below our window, so that it blocks the water. The problem is that it is very hard to get to this wall: it is too low to get to from our window, and too high to get to from her window. One can climb a high ladder from the street, but it is complex and expensive.

Is there a simpler solution for blocking the water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way 1**: The way you suggest ... a rain guard.  But not such a big and heavy one as in your photo.  Water falling at least 10cm away from the wall will not enter your neighbor's balcony.  It will fall to the street.  You only need to catch water falling directly down the wall.   To do that, install an aluminum strip, about 10cm wide, along the entire length of the neighbor's door, on the wall just above the door frame.  The strip should be angled downward to the left so the water it catches will fall off away from the balcony.  It should be easy enough to install a lightweight aluminum strip on the wall above the balcony using just glue.

The problem with Way 1 is that you don't want to pour water on pedestrians below, either, do you?

I note that her air conditioner, *but not yours* has a drip tube directing water away from the sidewalk below.   Hence, Way 2.

**Way 2:**. Install a drip tube on your air conditioner.  Direct it down the wall and then to wherever her drip tubes are going.  THEN install drip trays below your plants, as suggested by @SolarMike.  Now, here's the innovation: make small holes in the drip trays and use irrigation tubing to direct the water into the air conditioner's drip tray.  Drip irrigation parts are cheap and easy to get and easy to adapt to new situations.

**Way 3**: Don't water so much that water is overflowing!  As long as you're contemplating "Way 2" and going out to buy drip irrigation parts .... why not just use them for the intended purpose?  Hose up all your potted plants with a single drip irrigation zone, and if you don't have a hose tap on your balcony just connect the zone to a bucket on a table, and fill it before bed.   Even if a little water drips down, it'll dry up before she sees it in the morning.

Comment: Thanks! Way 3 is what we ended up doing. Since we don't have a tap near the window, we bought a solar pump that waters all our plants automatically. It saves us both time and water, and saves trouble to our neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

So put all the pots into larger waterproof pots and then remove the excess water after the water has drained through.

Don’t leave them sitting in inches of water - unless they are swamp plants.

Comment: If the OP is in Israel (as the Israeli flag may indicate), there will be no need to remove excess water. It will dry in _very_ short order.

Comment: @FreeMan not quickly enough to stop the drips, otherwise they would not have posted... obviously not enough time for the drips to evaporate before getting to the windows below even with the hot climate... :)

Comment: I've seen it go from deluge to bone dry in 30 minutes there. If there were a second pot catching the overflow, it wouldn't need to be emptied.

Comment: @FreeMan I don't know, flying your country's flag like that is also an *expat* thing, i.e. you're in a foreign country and saying "I'm from there". The only US flags I see displayed like that in the US are black, white and blue, not a good thing!

Comment: Having just taken a look at the OP's profile, he's faculty at Ariel University and indicates his location _is_ Israel. (Man, why didn't any of us do that earlier?)

Comment: How did this get from installing a rain guard to guessing the climate in the present location of a patriotic expat?   Anyway, even in Israel, the climate is not dry in all places or at all times of year.   I think the avoidance of pouring dirty water on your neighbor's balcony is worthy of an actual answer.  :)